# Docker and Makefile Build

Tags: docker

I am hoping to use `Dockerfile` to build a fairly large codebase from source. The source code is written in C++ and build system is written in **Makefile**. Currently my `Dockerfile` goes like the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        vim g++ make && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY src /src # `src` folder contains the source code
WORKDIR /src
RUN make && make all
```

My major concern about this `Dockerfile` is that - Suppose that later on when I modify some tiny portion of the large codebase and re-execute the `docker build` command, which of the followings would happen?

1. Docker does the copying once again and figure out the build dependency of `make`.
2. Docker does nothing because the `Dockerfile` has not been changed.
3. Docker builds the entire codebase from the very beginning.

If the second or the third happens, is there any better option than putting the `make` command inside the `Dockerfile`? Should I execute it as part of `docker run` and mount the source code directory onto the Docker container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Docker does the copying once again and figure out the build dependency of make

**Yes**. It will copy your source to the specified destination in the container

> Docker does nothing because the Dockerfile has not been changed.

**No**. Docker will re-build your code even if you don't change the `Dockerfile`. This is because you changed the code base. If you didn't change the code base though it may do nothing since it can just retrieve the last layer that was built. (Note that the order of commands may alter the caching logic here)

> Docker builds the entire codebase from the very beginning.

**By default yes**. If you didn't copy pre-compiled artifacts into your container (which you shoudn't) then it will re-build your code from the ground up.

> is there any better option than putting the make command inside the Dockerfile?

Putting the `make` command in the `Dockerfile` **is the better option** here. One of the most important reasons why people use Docker (if not the most important) is to have **predictable builds**

## Note

A possible *"better way"* is to use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to separate your *"builder container"* and your *"container that holds the binary"*. This also gives you smaller *"final"* images since you can build them from [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) or [scratch](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch). That way your *"final"* container won't have to include unnecessary librairies/software.

Answer (score 2):

There's two possible answers to this.

If you have a `.dockerignore` file that includes `*.o`, or you have a separate build tree set up, then when you reach the `RUN make` line, the image will contain all of the source files and none of the object files, and the build will run completely from scratch.  This is the "purest" answer – you should get a very consistent build output – but it can in fact take a while.

If you don't have this then whatever you have built locally will get copied into the image, including its timestamps, and you'll get an incremental build.  But, it means that different people who build the same application from the same partial source tree will get different results; in an Autoconf-based project entire application features could be gated on whether a particular developer had some library installed on their host or not.

If you already have a mostly Make-based build system, I might stick with that and prefer a "do everything in Make" model to a "do everything in Docker" model.  In GNU Make you could write a fragment like this:

```
DOCKER_TAG := $(shell date +%Y%m%d)

.PHONY: docker

docker:
        $(MAKE) install DESTDIR=docker/dist
        cp Dockerfile docker
        docker build -t me/myapp:$(DOCKER_TAG) docker
```

This also gives you the practical effects of a multi-stage build (you've precompiled the application so you don't need a toolchain in the Docker pipeline anywhere.  In the same way that you would `sudo make install` now, you'd `sudo make docker` to produce the Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the answers.

So after doing some experiments myself. Given below is the conclusion that I have

- As @molamk answered, **Docker will copy the files and start the build from the very beginning**. The reason is because for `COPY` command, Docker uses the checksum mechanism to verify whether the files have been changed or not. Hence, Docker is able to figure out exactly whether a recopy is necessary and invalidate all the cached layers (including `make` build) after the `COPY` layer.
- In my case where I want to modify the part of the large codebase, including the build inside the Dockerfile is a terrible idea, since this means that everytime I need to wait for several hours for changes to take effect. Therefore, I only included the build prerequisite in the Dockerfile and mounted the source directory to the container obtained by running the prerequisite image.